# Are Iterative calculation is possible in python?

Tags: python, jupyter, data-science

Please help me in this problem

Are iterative calculations are possible in Python?

I have the table which contains material number, stock and usage. I am giving input as 20

```
Material   stock       usage       material availability(stock -input)

100           10          2                 -10

101           10          2                 -10

102           10          2                 -10

101            5          2                  -5
```

If I give input parameter as 20, it should subtract from stock and if you have the same material number it should hit first material number and then pass to the second material number.

I have 2 of the same material numbers if I give input as 20 first it should hit the first material (101) gives as -10 and passes through the same material number(101) which has stock as 5 (-10+5) gives -5.

Thanks

chaitanya

Comment: Please clarify your question: What are you trying to do? What kind of "table" are you using? Pandas? SQL?
Giving a "before / operation / after" comparison of your table would probably be a good step to clarify your request. Also, if you already have exisiting code, please provide a minimal working example for us to test.

Comment: Please write your question as actual code (not in words!), pointing the parts where you're having trouble. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, you must show some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [
    {
        'material_number': 100,
        'stock': 10,
        'usage': 2
    },
    {
        'material_number': 101,
        'stock': 10,
        'usage': 2
    },
    {
        'material_number': 102,
        'stock': 10,
        'usage': 2
    },
    {
        'material_number': 101,
        'stock': 5,
        'usage': 2
    },
]

params = 20

update = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    update_dict = {}
    flag = None
    for j in range(len(update)):
        if update[j]['material_number'] == data[i]['material_number']:
            flag = j
    if flag != None:
        update_dict['material_number'] = data[i]['material_number']
        update_dict['stock'] = data[i]['stock'] + update[flag]['stock']
        update_dict['usage'] = data[i]['usage']
    else:
        update_dict['material_number'] = data[i]['material_number']
        update_dict['stock'] = data[i]['stock'] + (-params)
        update_dict['usage'] = data[i]['usage']

    update.append(update_dict)
print(update)
```

This is full code that you want. Try to check.

Comment: But when i add extra material number as 100 more it was not working.                        pls check this   { 'material_number': 100, 'stock': 10,'usage': 2 } .                               The same code above u had given has been executed.  this is the answer   [{'material_number': 100, 'stock': -10, 'usage': 2},                                               {'material_number': 101, 'stock': -10, 'usage': 2},                             {'material_number': 102, 'stock': -10, 'usage': 2}, {'material_number': 101, 'stock': -4, 'usage': 2}, {'material_number': 100, 'stock': -10, 'usage': 2}]

Comment: Use flag=None instead of flag=0.That will work good.

Comment: Its working fine now, Thanks :)